# MongoDB search: exact match and diacritic insensitivity (avoid tokenizer)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to search in a MongoDB collection field without diacritic sensitivity (it is a $text index) and I want to find only exact matches (not a .contains() or like).

The only solution I can think of is to configure the index of the documents to avoid the tokenizer. Therefore, I would have all the content of the field as a single token and it would only give me back the ones that matched exactly. Does anyone know how to do this, please?

Thank you so much!

Example: 
I try to search "iphone 7" in the field. 
I want it to give me back: "iphóne 7", "iphone 7".
What it gives me back: "iphóne 7", "iphone 7", "iphóne 7 64gb", "iphone 7 color blanco".

Answer (score 3):

you can set `$diacriticSensitive: <boolean>` value when doing text searches.

```
{
  $text:
    {
      $search: <string>,
      $language: <string>,
      $caseSensitive: <boolean>,
      $diacriticSensitive: <boolean>
    }
}
```

check this link for more detailed explanation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: Thanks! I was already doing that! I wanted to do the exact string match while using the $diacriticSensitive: <boolean>. I wanted to find only "iphóne 7" and "iphone 7". I didn't want to find an "iphóne 7 blablabla" if there was one.

But thanks for the answer. I think I was asking for an impossible, so I changed my approach and I now don't index the values as $text and do the text operations with my own code :)